# How can i change height size without any deterioration?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, resize, borders

I have a PNG, not PSD. It's size 29 x 126 but i want change this to 29 x 220px. What is good solution for this?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk3zy.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

slice the image above and below the '>' then move the three portions to top, centre, bottom, then either copy and paste a section from the top or bottom pieces (before the rounded corner) and place those in the gab - or take a 1 pixel slice and stretch it between the gaps ( though the latter is less advisable ) if you have any obvious cut lines, use the healing brush to tidy it up